# VSTS agent not picking up proxy address set

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've setup the build agent according to this [document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/start/proxyconfig.md)

[image: proxy file]

Content of the file is `http://192.168.2.101:8080`

However when the download artifact task run, the build artifact could not be download

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Download artifact'
##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
##[debug]=> True
##[debug]Result: True
Starting: Download artifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Download artifacts from file share
Description  : Download artifacts from a file share, like \\share\drop
Version      : 1.154.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-fileshare-artifacts
==============================================================================
##[debug]Using node path: C:\azagent\A1\externals\node\bin\node.exe
##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp
##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading INPUT_ARTIFACTNAME
##[debug]loading INPUT_DOWNLOADPATH
##[debug]loading INPUT_FILESHAREPATH
##[debug]loading INPUT_ITEMPATTERN
##[debug]loading INPUT_PARALLELIZATIONLIMIT
##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loaded 9
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
```

system diagnostics show that ProxyUrl is not being pickup despite me setting 1 in the file

I've also checked that Agent version is 2.181.2

Any idea on why the proxy url cannot be pick up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didnt put `.proxy` in the correct folder, I put it in the root directory of `C:\azagent` instead. The correct directory to put `.proxy` is at  `C:\azagent\A1`